# Free Software to Increase the Resolution of the Pictures

Tags: photos

I took some pictures from my Nikon 5000 Camera and uploaded them to Google Picasa. Picasa decreased the resolution of the image while uploading and now I have lost the originals.

Is there any free software I can use to increase the resolution of the images? Here is the information about one of the images:

```
ul 23, 2010
1338×1193 pixels – 98KB
Filename: DSC_0017.JPG
Camera: NIKON CORPORATION
Model: NIKON D5000
ISO: 200
Exposure: 1/200 sec
Aperture: 8.0
Focal Length: 55mm
Flash Used: Yes
Latitude: n/a
Longitude: n/a
```

Comment: Please don't use signatures or taglines in your posts. http://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can enlarge them, but once the high-resolution data are gone, they are just plain gone.  Enlarging them generally won't produce good looking pictures.

Irfanview can enlarge them for you.  http://www.irfanview.com/

Comment: Thanks Adam S!! Well... lesson learned to always make a backup of the originals and do not rely on Picasa.

Comment: If you'd still like to try an enlarge using IrfanView, don't use the default setting (which I think is linear) but take the slowest one (Lancozs). It makes a much smoother image than the other method, but it still won't be as sharp as the original.

Comment: My original image was 1338×1193 pixels (306KB) and I changed to 5000 X 4459 (6MB). The website where I am trying to upload has the requirement for 4.25 MB (2400 X 1800). What am I missing?

Comment: I do not think I should go with 5000 X 4459 since it will be extremely huge. When I set 2400 X 1800 in IrfanView the size comes as 2.4MB.

Comment: Also, what I am doing with IrfanView will be considered Upsizing the photo and the website (shutterstock) clearly says not to upsize more than 5 percent or account will be suspended.